# manage memory for memorystream

Tags: c#, memory, memorystream

Which is better for Memory ?
Which is lower in memory consumption?

```
byte[] Pic = (byte[])re.GetValue(4);
MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
MS.Write(Pic, 0, Pic.Length);
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(MS);
```

or

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])re.GetValue(4), true));
```

Comment: Benchmark it and see? ;-) I'd have expected the second to be better (ie lower) memory consumption but I'd be surprised if you noticed much difference. Mainly its based on the fact that there is no explicitly stored byte array in the second (Pic). Possibly the question should be why are you worrying? If there are specific concerns then you should test them, if there aren't specific concerns then you probably shouldn't be worrying...

Answer (score 2):

Second one will work faster and it will use less memory. When you initialize `MemoryStream` from constructor, bytes simply assigned to inner buffer (stream will be non-resizable):

```
public MemoryStream(byte[] buffer, bool writable)
{    
    _buffer = buffer;    
    _writable = writable;
    _exposable = false;
}
```

If you use parameterless constructor, stream will be resizable with initial capacity `0`. During writing new byte array will be created and values will be copied to internal buffer:

```
public MemoryStream()
{    
    _buffer = new byte[0];   
    _writable = true;
    _exposable = true;
}

public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // EnsureCapacity
    byte[] dst = new byte[_position + count];
    Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(_buffer, 0, dst, 0, _length);
    _buffer = dst;
    // Copy
    Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(buffer, offset, _buffer, _position, count);
}
```